# What's the average brix scale difference between Stowell's Evergreen and Blue Jade?

Tags: sweetcorn, brix-scale

My local plant sale allows the difference between Stowell's Evergreen and Blue Jade for the two types of corn for sale, and I'm wondering which one would be better if I can only choose between them for sweet corn this year. I'm specifically asking about the part you eat.

Answer (score 1):

The brix scale is not normally used to classify sweetcorn. The sugar content of any variety depends strongly on when it is harvested. Too early and the sugar hasn't been formed, too late and it has been converted into starch.

Varieties are classified into three groups on the basis of the genetics: "su" (standard, eat immediately after harvesting), "se" (sugar extended, can be stored up to 4 days without deterioration) and "sh2" (supersweet, 4 to 10 times the sugar content of su, can be stored up to 10 days without deterioration). SE and sh2 varieties are less hardy than su, and sh2 needs to be isolated from cross pollination by the other groups.

Blue Jade is fast maturing, small (1 meter height) and has bright blue coloured ears.

Stowell's Evergreen is a heirloom variety (white) and one of the slowest maturing varieties still available. However the whole stalk with immature ears can be harvested before the first frost would kill it, and the cobs cut and used up to 4 weeks later - hence the name "evergreen".

So the "best" choice for you depends mainly on your climate and growing conditions.